# Android Scroll ScrollView automatically in onCreate method

Tags: android

I have some kinde of calendar and I use ScrollView  to scroll to days 
I want it on create it will be scroll able to today date 
here is the cod I use:

```
scrollV.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scr.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                scrollV.scrollTo(0,3);                          }
        });
    }
});
```

3 is just for test I'll change it later;  thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate what your issue is?

Comment: I want it to scroll to changed index when launching the activity it just not scrolling it showing first index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it
here is the answer for any one need it :
Just put a timer in OnCreate method or in onCreateView if it is a fragment

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        list.smoothScrollToPosition(day);
                    }
                },
                4000
        );
```

day is the variable you want to the list to scroll to it's day of month for me ,
list is the list view

Answer (score 1):

```
final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview));
 scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
 });
```

Or ether use this.

```
 final long totalScrollTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;
 final int scrollPeriod = 20;
 final int heightToScroll = -8;

timerDown = new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod) {
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  scrollview.scrollListBy(heightToScroll);
}

 public void onFinish() {
  timerDown.cancel();
 }
```

};